# Why does my CSS stop working when I put it in an external file instead of inside the <header> tag?

Tags: html, css, width

This works (i.e. the input sliders are correct width):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

      div {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }

      code {
        color: gray;
      }

      .slider {
        width: 250px;
        height: 25px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      <code>/qc/lfo/1</code><br />
      <input class="slider" id="/qc/lfo/1" type="range" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <code>/range/1-3</code><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/1', parseInt(this.value))" /><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/2', parseInt(this.value))" /><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/3', parseInt(this.value))" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However when I load the CSS from an external file the width styling is lost (but not the other styles):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="websocket.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      <code>/qc/lfo/1</code><br />
      <input class="slider" id="/qc/lfo/1" type="range" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <code>/range/1-3</code><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/1', parseInt(this.value))" /><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/2', parseInt(this.value))" /><br />
      <input class="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" onchange="send('/range/3', parseInt(this.value))" />
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

With CSS stylesheet file:

```
div {
   margin-bottom: 1em;
}

code {
  color:maroon;
  font-family: Geneva
}

.slider {
  width: 200 px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

The sliders are not correct width, yet the other styles colour; font & margin are correct. Previewing in Coda 1.7 Coda 2.0 and Safari — all incorrect width. Have tried making parent element wider and a bunch of other random things... what am I not getting here?

---

Oh dear could it be the space between "200" and "px" I;ve retyped this CSS code many times I couldn't have kept doing same mistake could I?

---

Another thing that was tricking me was the times I did have the CSS right (no space before 'px'), it was not updating in Safari when I hit Cmd+Opt+"B" in Coda. Only when I reloaded the page (Cmd+"R" in Safari did it look correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just write

```
width: 200px;
```

instead of

```
width: 200 px;
```

Comment: why would separating the 200 and the px matter in an external stylesheet but not when directly on the page? I've never encountered this problem before so I'm just wondering

Comment: oh nm, it's differently written in each example. :)

Comment: Changing the spacing fixed it in my side-by-side in Chrome. My best guess is that the browser is doing what it always does with text nodes, which is ignores whitespace as much as possible. But when it imports the stylesheet, it imports it directly as a stylesheet object, so the syntax error gets caught.  I'll test, but I'll put even money that if you "correctly" wrapped your style element rules in a CDATA wrapper, it would break in the head element as well. Will post if I'm right.

Comment: Ah wait, just saw that the space isn't in the inline stylesheet. Breaks with space either way. But I stand behind my theory should something similar but more mysterious should arise.

Answer (score 0):

```
code {
  color:maroon;
  font-family: Geneva
}
```

There's a ";" (semicolon) missing after "Geneva". Could that be the problem?

Comment: that shouldn't do anything since there's a bracket there anyways

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem in my experience is that you reference the css wrongly.

The easiest way to check is to open the web inspector (in chrome for example) an then go to console-view and check if you have any 404 errors.

Comment: Like I said, I was editting the other style declarations in the file and they were updating so CSS file was loading.

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw that you had got the answer you were looking for already, byt I thought it would be a good idea to post this for any future visitors :)